# Permission denied when accessing backup directory

Tags: macos, itunes, backup, permission

I used iTunes to make a backup of my iPhone. I can see the backup directory using Finder, at `/Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`. Strangely, when doing something like

```
ls "/Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Application Support/MobileSync"
```

or

```
du -ms "/Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup"
```

I get an error message i.e. *ls: MobileSync: Operation not permitted*. But when I do a

```
ls -ld "/Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Application Support/MobileSync"
```

I see

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 ronaldfischer  staff  96 Sep 15 14:08 /Users/ronaldfischer/Library/Application Support/MobileSync
```

Hence I should have suffient permissions, plus *Finder* too can go into this directory without requiring me to switch to root rights.

Where does the permission problem come from?

**UPDATE**:

Running `xattr` on the directory `MobileSync` showed that it has the attribute *com.apple.quarantine* being set. This attribute is usually set on (usually an executable) file which is downloaded from somewhere, and ensures that MacOS is asking you "Do you really trust this file?" the first time it is opened. Maybe the attribute has been set because backing up my iPhone in effect means that external programs are downloaded.

However, this is likely not the reason of the strange behaviour, because I also get an *operation not permitted*, when I try to remove this attribute using *xattr -d*. Furthermore, @Seamus said in his comment, that he did not have this attribute being set, but also has no permission. Perhaps it is a glitch in this OS version? I'm still running Mojave (10.14.6).

Comment: The '@' character at the end of the permissions list on /MobileSync indicates that it has extended attributes. I just looked at the same directory on my user account, and this directory _does not_ have extended attributes. You can look at which attributes are set by using the `xattr` terminal command. Here's [an excellent guide](https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/03/view-remove-extended-attributes-file-mac/) to using `xattr` command to delve further into your mystery.

Comment: @IconDaemon: That oughta' be an answer :)

Comment: Well, its a trouble shooting comment to further help user1934428 figure out why that directory has the xattr flag set. It is not an answer, _per se_. As I stated, the equivalent directory on my Mac does not have the xattr flag set, and I can't divine why it is happening on the OP's directory. Should the OP find out why, and fix the problem, my hope is that it is reported back and that I helped to find a solution.

Comment: @IconDaemon: Yeah - it's confusing... I tried this on my Mojave and Catalina systems just now. Like the OP, `ls -la` gets an error: `ls: MobileSync: Operation not permitted`. But *unlike* the OP, I see no **extended attributes** when I do `ls -ld`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be able to read the directory if you grant Full Disk Access to your terminal program (e.g. Terminal.app or [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com)).

In macOS 13 Ventura: Apple Menu › System Settings › Privacy & Security › Full Disk Access.

In previous verisons of macOS: Apple Menu › System Preferences › Security & Privacy › Privacy › Full Disk Access.

Comment: The Terminal.app doesn't have "Settings". It has "Preferences", but there is no "Security&Privacy" in this menu. Only "General", "Profiles", "Window Groups" and "Encodings". This is "Terminal 2.9.5".

Comment: Sorry, I meant system settings. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This worked on macOS 11.6 Big Sur when running `rsync` (macOS version) from a bash script - many Apple-managed files under `~/Library` gave 'operation not permitted.  Granting Full Disk Access to `/usr/bin/rsync` did nothing, but granting this to Terminal.app worked.  Perhaps because Terminal.app is more of a 'macOS native' app and its privileges are inherited down to bash and rsync?

Comment: @RichVel Sorry, by "terminal program," I meant Terminal.app and similar. I've updated the answer.